How are sock-puppet accounts dealt with on CSE?
Yesterday I discovered a new user account on CSE which had a duplicate account - the only difference being one was in green and the other was in a blue-grey colour. The moderators quickly closed down both accounts because they were being used to answer each others questions and upvote their answers.
This morning I looked at the "New Users" pages and discovered that there are about 180 pages of what look like sock-puppet accounts. In other words, a staggering 6,480 bogus accounts!
Apart from flagging obvious spam posts, how can CSE contributors identify these sock-puppet accounts and what is the procedure for removing them permanently?

Just FYI, having multiple accounts are permitted, unless they're interacting and benefiting each other. So, the first thing is to see whether they interact with each other.
